# IE Opacity Problem in Nested Elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer, opacity, inheritance

Has anybody found a solution for this ? http://seanmonstar.com/post/709013028/ie-opacity-ignores-positioned-children

I’ve been searching for hours now and can’t find a fix. I know that filter:inherit works but I actually need the filter to give opacity to one of the nested elements…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this example which seems to work: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDnCu/84/)

So I'm using jquery to fade in and out which effects the opacity, if you remove position:relative; from #toggle_me; you'll find the positioned element has an issue, so the solution is to have position:relative; on the parent.

Also in the jquery area of code you'll see this.style.removeAttribute('filter'); that stops IE strangely rendering the text when it fades back up.

Comment: still does not work - look http://jsfiddle.net/digitalzoomstudio/yWrFN/2/ [ I could do with a working example without animation ]

Comment: Oh ok that appears to have nothing whatsoever to do with the http://seanmonstar.com link you posted initially. You simply want to have a child element of a fully transparent element to be NOT fully transparent. You can't do that on any browser.

Comment: hey man, it's actually the other way around .. and it works on every browser but ie .. I don't think there is a solution to this other then the ones I posted.

Comment: Changing your example to use standard opacity: http://jsfiddle.net/yWrFN/22/ and viewing in Firefox, you cannot see the child element, so how is this working in other browsers?

Comment: Why is this answer accepted in the first place, because it doesn't address the problem but mitigates it using client script. Tags on the questions don't mention scripting and this should be resolved using CSS only.

Comment: I think it is a CSS only solution you set the parent element to have position:relative. The script bit was just to get rid of blocky text I was seeing on IE at the time. My advice for older versions of IE would be just provide basic support, don't worry if it's not perfect, (IE 8-) usage figures are much lower these days (and it's only going in one direction), so better to put your effort into more polish and functionality for modern browsers instead.